# how to implement Access Level for executing APIs in API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a website that is created with Vue JS and it calls my APIs which are implemented in AWS API Gateway, and these APIs are executing my AWS Lambdas.
and also I created an AWS Cognito User Pool that is storing and authenticating my users when they signup and sign in

I want to control the user's access when they call APIs.
like I want to have some users inside one specific user group in the Cognito User Pool and give an IAM Role to that group and inside that Role I want to specify which APIs this group's users should have access to call

and here is the problem :

after doing all these, Access Level is not correct

now I have a user group called USERS which has a few Cognito authenticated users.
and I have this policy for my IAM role which is connected to the USERS group

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:*:xxxxx/*/GET/v1/assignments"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

also, I created a JWT authorizer in the API Gateway (which is HTTP Protocol, not REST) and give it my User Pool and Audience ID.

after users signing in process, I get an access token and an Id token, I tried passing both of them in the Authorization Header but none of them worked for me.

I also created another API Gateway which is REST protocol but it's not working too.

is there any missing part that I forgot to do?
do I use the right JWT in my request's header? (Access Token or Id Token)
is there any better way that I can implement the Access Level Control on my APIs executions?